# Type '...' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It has been more than a weak suffering with web.config issues, and here is the last issue i am in as the title says.

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Test page

```
@model Typo
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@DateTime.Now</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Stack

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Type 'ASP._Page_default_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.]
   System.Web.UI.Util.CheckAssignableType(Type baseType, Type type) +9706663
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +66
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType) +29
   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +343
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance(IVirtualPathFactory factory, String virtualPath) +236
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +261
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance(IVirtualPathFactory factory, String virtualPath) +132
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory) +58
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath) +59
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +462
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +157
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Does it tell you what type it is that doesn't inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'?

Comment: turn on tracing and view the logs & stack traces.  If you're using a logging framework redirect the tracing to it via your web.config.

Comment: Having glanced at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042929/type-does-not-inherit-from-system-web-webpages-webpage:  what does your controller look like?

Comment: @JNYRanger i am not using a logging library

Comment: @SLaks added the trace

Comment: @AnnL added the stack trace

Comment: This error usually indicates an MVC or Razor library version mismatch in your configuration and/or project file. Please post the contents of your `/Views/web.config` file and your `.csproj` file(s).

Comment: Also, have a look at the question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715675/the-view-must-derive-from-webviewpage-or-webviewpagetmodel-html-mvcsitemap/28719170#28719170).

Comment: offtopic... this shit of a programming language drove me nuts the same way like you. 2x `web.config`, `webpages:Enabled` true or false... Mismatching configuration and hidden files everywhere... inheritence issues all around. The least friendly system ever developed. Gj Microsoft... topics are beeing created and never solved & between 1-5 yrs old...